# Multiple runs of VBA code

Tags: vba, excel

I have a code that I want to run several times but for now I can run it only once unless I made some changes at data sheet name.

My code:

```
Public Sub MyFilter()
    Dim lngStart As Date, lngEnd As Date
    lngStart = Range("b2").Value 'assume this is the start date
    lngEnd = Range("b3").Value 'assume this is the end date
    Range("q:q").AutoFilter field:=1, _
        Criteria1:=">=" & lngStart, _
        Operator:=xlAnd, _
        Criteria2:="<=" & lngEnd


           Range("A1:s3000").Select
    Range("A:A").Activate
    Selection.Copy
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    Sheets("Sheet2").Select
    Sheets("Sheet2").Name = "FilterData"
    Range("A1").Select
    Selection.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
        :=False, Transpose:=False
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Cells.Select
    Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Rows("1:1").Select
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection.Interior
        .Pattern = xlSolid
        .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
        .Color = 15773696
        .TintAndShade = 0
        .PatternTintAndShade = 0
    End With
    Selection.AutoFilter
    Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    Range("A2").Select

End Sub
```

Before I execute it I create sheet2 manually but if I want to run it again I cant because I already have "FilterData" sheet data name.

How can I modify the code to:
1. Run it without the need to enter "sheet2" manually.
2. To run it more than once.
Thanks!

Comment: Once you have named a sheet `Filter Data` you couldn't run it again because that sheet already exists. Does each new sheet need a new name?

Comment: No, we can call it as we want.. even 1..2..3...4

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you create a new sheet in Excel it becomes the active sheet, so instead of specifically selecting sheet 2 you can use `activesheet`

```
Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
With ActiveSheet
    .Range("A1").PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValues, Operation:=xlNone, SkipBlanks _
    :=False, Transpose:=False
    .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Cells.Select
    .Cells.EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Rows("1:1").Select
    .Application.CutCopyMode = False
    With Selection
         With .Interior
            .Pattern = xlSolid
            .PatternColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            .Color = 15773696
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .PatternTintAndShade = 0
        End With
        .AutoFilter
    End With
    .Columns("A:A").EntireColumn.AutoFit
    .Range("A2").Select
End With
```

Then you can manually rename all your new sheets.

Alternatively if you want to loop a set number of times you could wrap the whole thing in a loop and increment sheet names:

```
For i = 1 to 4
    Sheets.Add After:=ActiveSheet
    With ActiveSheet
        .Name = "FilterData " & i
*rest of the code here*
    End With
Next i
```

This will create 4 sheets called FilterData 1, 2, 3 etc, but again this will throw an error if you already have sheets called those things.

Comment: `Workbook.Sheets.Add` also happens to return an object reference pointing to the `Worksheet` object that was added, so a better solution would be to hold that reference in a local variable, and code against that variable instead of assuming `ActiveSheet` will remain active throughout the execution of the code.